# Converting a polygon into a raster using R

Tags: raster, shapefile, r

I'm trying to convert a shapefile into a raster within R. My approach is to read in the raster as follows:

```
library(rgdal) # Loads SP package by default
demo <- readOGR('F:/data/', 'shapefile') # Creates a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame class (sp)
```

This works fine, and I can plot it. However it is a large shapefile and I want to convert it into a raster. I've tried the following:

```
r <- raster(ncol=180, nrow=180)
Demo_ras = rasterize(r, demo, 'pop')  # pop is an integer here
```

Error message:

```
Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function "rasterize", for signature "RasterLayer", "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
```

I'm slightly confused which is the correct order of the arguments. I've also tried this:

```
Demo_ras = rasterize(demo, r, 'pop')
```

Which results in the follow error:

```
Error in .polygonsToRaster(x, y, ...) : 
  polygon and raster have no overlapping areas
```

While it makes sense that a raster cannot be generated for an area that does not cover the `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, I'm not sure what information I need to specify so that the raster should contain the `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` area.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The rasterize() function wants to have the shape (polygon) first then the raster by default, hence your first error. The second command you've shown `Demo_ras = rasterize(demo, r, 'pop')` is the correct way around, but as you discovered it needs the extents to match!

You can assign the extents of the raster to cover the same extents of the polygon:

```
extent(r) <- extent(demo)
```

... this should work for the example you've provided, as long as 'pop' is the correct  name of a variable in 'demo'. The following worked just now (R 2.14 / OSX), where AREA is a real number column in boundary.shp:

```
poly <- readOGR("/workingdirectory", "boundary") # does not work  with final slash '/' 
r <- raster(ncol=180, nrow=180)
extent(r) <- extent(poly)
rp <- rasterize(poly, r, 'AREA')
```

Comment: Saw your edit and checked again - the final forward slash is apparently optional on OSX, I take it not with Windows? Worth knowing!

Comment: hmmm, I had a problem with the slash on both OSX and Windows.. not sure if we are using the same version or not.

Comment: OSX 10.7.2 / R 2.14 on mine; definitely works either way 'round. What are you using?

Comment: To automatize conversion, I wrote this: https://github.com/brry/misc/blob/master/shp2raster.R